# Sort ArrayList by double values

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have an ArrayList with double values:

```
double distance = HaversineAlgorithm.HaversineInKM(lat, lon,
                    stop.getStopLat(), stop.getStopLon());
distanceList.add(distance);
```

I can get the smallest value in the List with this:

```
int minIndex = distanceList.indexOf(Collections.min(distanceList));
currentList.get(minIndex); //it is the smallest value element
```

But I have to know the second smallest value and the third smallest value element too. But I don't know how.

I tried to sort the List with this:

```
Collections.sort(distanceList);
```

But it's not working. I mean the last index of the List isn't the smallest or the highest value.

Is here anybody who can explain me how I can solve this ? :)

Comment: Once sorted, the min element is at index 0 (assuming sorting is in natural order), so you want element at index 1. Maybe you should clarify "But it's not working."

Comment: That will sort in ascending order, so, after `sort()`, `distanceList.get(0)` is the smallest, `distanceList.get(1)` is the second smallest and so on...

Comment: `currentList.get(minIndex + 1);` for second largest and `currentList.get(minIndex + 2);` for third largest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code looks good:

```
int minIndex = distanceList.indexOf(Collections.min(distanceList));
currentList.get(minIndex); //it is the smallest value element
```

So since everything is in sorted order, you can get the smallest, 2nd smallest, and 3rd smallert value bying directly calling the index.

```
    currentList.get(0);
    currentList.get(1);
    currentList.get(2);
```

Comment: thank you, and sorry, my question wasn't clear enough.. :( i have two ArrayList: currentList which includes entity object.. and with HaversineAlgorithm i'm checking the distance beetween two gps coordinates.. i put the values to another ArrayList this is distanceList.. i know which is the smallest double value in my distanceList but i dont know how to point to the another ArrayList which includes my entity-s.. :) maybe i should use HashMap..

Comment: `HashMap` sounds a like a better idea instead of using two arrays. Try and see if it works, if it didn't post a new question and we will help you